# Is it possible that an heavier object is attracted with a higher speed than a lighter by a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

Imagine there is a magnet with a lot of Tesla power. At a big distance from it are two balls of iron one of 10kg and an other of 100kg.

Now I suppose that the lighter one will initialy be attracted with a higher speed to the magnet than the heavier one. But imagine the distance and the power of the magnet can be made of any size, could it be possible that the heaviest ball could run into the lighter and arrive first? Or isn't that in any case possible?

As far as possible I would forget things like airresistance and gravity.

Comment: I do not agree, magnetization is the magnetic moment per volume... it is trivially the same as both balls are made of iron.

Comment: Attraction is not measured by speed. What are the forces, and what influences them. @Lacek - you might want to rethink your comment given that iron is a ferromagnetic material with a hysteresis curve. Now, that may not matter in this particular case, but there will be differences if one ball has a net residual magnetic field and another one doesn't.

Comment: True, but the residual magnetic field is I guess beyond the scope of this question as the author suggests that the only feature differentiating the balls is their mass, not the initial magnetization.